# How to store pointer value (in C)

Tags: c, pointers

I'm searching for a way to get a pointer value and store it in a string. Do you think there is any way to do that in C ? (*By value i mean what you get from a printf using %p).
Thanks a lot for your help !

*example from cplusplus.com - > printf("%p", *a) -> b8000000*

Comment: I'm sure this is not the first such time..

Comment: You need to clarify your question, and maybe search around a little more.  This is a pretty basic operation.

Comment: By "a pointer's address", do you mean the address of a pointer object, or the *contents* of the pointer object (which is also an address)? And why do you want to store it in a char array? Do you mean you want a human-readable representation of a pointer?

Comment: Guys , Luci seems to be new to stack overflow. Pls don't discourage new members from using stack overflow by giving down votes.

Comment: @luci -- A pointer is either 32 or 64 bit wide depending on the CPU architecture and a char is typically 8 bit wide -- did you means "char-pointer array"?  If so, it is just a matter of casting.

Comment: Sorry if it is not easily understandable, Im going to edit it but I'll also write it here, so the thing is I want to take the value of the address of a given pointer and store it somewhere. In a nutshell, I want to be able to take what you get by using %p in printf and put that in a string.

Comment: Now that you've added a clearer explanation, please go ahead and delete the old one. We don't need to see the history.

Comment: One more improvement you can make: The phrase "a pointer's address" really means the address *of* a pointer object, not the address *stored in* a pointer object. Rather than "a pointer's address", just say "a pointer value". If you have a working example using `printf`, it would be helpful to include that as an unambiguous explanation of what you want to store in the string.

Comment: @Keith Thanks a lot for your help ! I'll try to follow your advices for my potential next question.

Comment: In your example, can you show the declaration of `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf` or `snprintf` with the `"%p"` format.

For example:

```
char s[40];
int obj = 42;
int *ptr = &obj;

snprintf(s, sizeof s, "%p", (void*)ptr);
```

The cast to `void*` is needed because that's the type expected by the `"%p"` format specifier.

The width of the output is system-specific, but it's not likely to be wider than 40 characters.

You can check the return value of `snprintf` to see whether the target array was actually long enough (see the documentation).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! That's perfect. Though, I want to ask, is there any way to get the address without using any library function ? If i can I prefer to use as few functions I don't fully understand as possible as I'm still learning. But if that's not possible then it's already far better than nothing !

Comment: @LuciDyevan: It's possible, but there's no point in not using the library for something like this.

Comment: I see thanks, well if it's that much more easy using libraries, then I won't complain !